# Speed up future_sapply gsub

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gsub, sapply

I am using `sapply` to recode letters in a large data table with 872440 rows and 480 columns with the following Code

```
x<-1:nrow(testmerge)#row number 
y<-2:ncol(testmerge)  #column start recode 
rm<-future_sapply(x, function(x) testmerge[x,y] <- gsub('B', testmerge[x,1], testmerge[x,y]))
```

`testmerge[x,1]` indicates the letter I want to use for recoding is in column 1 of the data set.This letter changes in each row.

My Problem is that the whole process of recoding takes forever, although I am using the `future_sapply` function to perform the Task in parallel

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess,workers=6) 
library(boot)
options(future.globals.maxSize=4000000000000)
```

I am running on a Windows PC with 30GB RAM

I would appreciate any advice to speed up the process.

Example Input:

`recode test1   test2   test3
C   AB  BB  AB
T   BB  AB  AA
G   AA  BB  BB`

Output I like to obtain:

`recode test1   test2   test3
C   AC  CC  AC
T   TT  AT  AA
G   AA  GG  GG`

Comment: Do you want to replace letters *within* a string or do you want to replace the entire string. In other words, do your fields look like `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, or like `'Foo'`, `'Bar'`, `'ABBC'`? If the former, then you can simplify and speed up the code substantially.

Comment: I want to replace letters within a string